# Distance between points on a circle

Tags: geometry

A, B, C, D are points on a circle with AB=5 cm, BC=12 cm, AC=13 cm and AD=7cm. What is the closest approximation of CD?

Comment: What do mean by closest approximation ? What is the motivation for this rather articicial question ? What have you attempted ?

Comment: The question was asked in one national entrance exam in India and I have just copied the question and asked as it is in this forum. please guide through steps of solving the question.

Comment: Just to understand what you are asking, what is *the closest approximation* of $\pi$? I guess it is $\pi$, but in such a case, why not to ask just for the length of $CD$?

Comment: @Jack Yes it is about finding the length of CD .

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: The triangle ABC is a right-angled triangle $$5^2+12^2=13^2$$
 This means AC lies on the diameter of the circle. Punt D lies on the circumference of the circle, which means that the triangle ACD is a right-angled triangle. The shortest distance of CD is given by $$13^2-7^2={CD}^2 \implies  \sqrt{120} = CD$$

Comment: Thanks so much for the explanation.